# Unable to connect to localhost in browser after installing XAMPP successfully

Tags: 12.04, apache2, xampp, localhost

I have successfully installed XAMPP 1.5.3 [following this guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=223410) on Ubuntu 12.04 and it started with no errors.

```
$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.5.3a...
XAMPP: Starting Apache with SSL (and PHP5)...
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

But when I open `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1/` in Firefox I get the *Unable to connect* error.

After I turned out to be unsuccessful, I changed the port in `httpd.conf` [as described here](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/07/how-to-change-xampp-server-port/) from `80` to `81` and attempted to open `http://localhost:81/` and `http://127.0.0.1:81/`, but I got the same result.

#### Edit

The output of `netstat -tlnp`:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State     PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN          23369/mysqld    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23352/proftpd: (acc
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20196/dnsmasq   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      929/cupsd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      929/cupsd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:44166               :::*                    LISTEN      23848/java
```

Comment: what about http://localhost/xampp/ ?

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo netstat -tlnp` so we can see the open ports.

Comment: You are using a very old version of xampp its up to version 1.8.0 now.`http://localhost` should be all thats needed from default web browser

Comment: i realised the oldness of it after i installed (just copy pasted the instructions). i need it to do some quick testing on a web app i'm working on, but if no quick fix is to be found i will try to upgrade and see if that does it. still... i found it to be an issue an just in case it may occur later again, is good to learn a few extra things.

Comment: @user60333 yes, i did test the localhost/xampp/index.php and 127.0.0.1/xampp/index.php

Answer (score 1):

According to the output of `netstat`, the Apache webserver fails to open the listening port. You should download [the newest version of XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html) and follow the instructions on the site.

If *XAMPP* is ran with default configuration, the output  should look something like this:

```
whisperity@localdomain:~$ sudo netstat -tlnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5235/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5701/httpd      
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      22965/proftpd: (acc
```

Comment: i'm giving it a try and will let you know. thanks a lot

Comment: I'm having trouble downloading the latest version (poor connection), and i'm trying [another way](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-ubuntu.html) since that's waht i'm really interested in.

Comment: @claudia The problem is with Apache's configuration (that's why the listener daemon does not start) files (`/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf` and `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-*.conf`), not PHP.

Answer (score -3):

first show ur c:/windows/prefetch find the file httpd.exe missing download to putit prefetch folder then msvcr100.dll file also missing in system32 folder so this also download to putit
installing wamp or xammp server u will get dialog box firebox want to default browser
click no.Then browse window shows find  explorer.exe click then press open button  on that window.then next and finsh.
work for fine.........
goodluck.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! These appear to be instructions to fix a similar problem on Windows rather than this problem on Ubuntu. If that is not the case, I recommend copy-editing this post for grammar and sentence structure to clarify what exactly you are recommending.