# How to get rid of "Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... failed: Connection refused."?

Tags: 14.04, php, eclipse, localhost

I started learning PHP a week ago and I installed Eclipse for PHP. I have tried some basic codes since but today, when I runned a code to create a txt file (using fopen, fwrite, fclose), Eclipse said:

> Unable to load page
>
> Problem occurred while loading the URL http://localhost/test/newfile.php
>
> Cannot connect to destination (localhost)

It is the same php file I used since the beginning so it is quite weird.

**I am very new to Linux so I do not know what kind of information to provide so someone can help me.** I checked other related questions and I could not understand all the information guys provided.

I use ubuntu 14.04.

Nevertheless, I tried to type *wget 127.0.0.1* in the terminal and the response was:

> --2015-08-11 21:07:35--  http://127.0.0.1/
>
> Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... failed: Connection refused.

I am not sure what to do now.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that, on your system (`localhost`) there is no program listening to `TCP port 80`. You need to start a webserver, e.g., `apache2` and configure it to handle your requests. Reread the beginning of your course, and see what it says about webserver requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! The Linux section in the book I use (Learning PHP, MySQL & JavaScript, 4th Edition) being quite succinct, I looked for how to start my webserver elsewhere and I found the answer I needed here (http://askubuntu.com/questions/164652/unable-to-connect-to-localhost-in-browser-after-installing-xampp-successfully).